# Remainder - My code is not correct, but why is it working?

Tags: ruby

Yesterday I completed an exercise (9.5) from the book "Learn to Program" from Chris Pine.
It's an integer to Old-school Roman numerals converter.

This is how I did it:

```
def old_roman_numeral number
    roman_number = ""
    while number != 0
        if number % 1000 == 0
            number -= 1000
            roman_number += "M"
            next
        elsif number % 500 == 0
            number -= 500
            roman_number += "D"
            next
        elsif number % 100 == 0
            number -= 100
            roman_number += "C"
            next
        elsif number % 50 == 0
            number -= 50
            roman_number += "L"
            next
        elsif number % 10 == 0
            number -= 10
            roman_number += "X"
            next
        elsif number % 5 == 0
            number -= 5
            roman_number += "V"
            next
        else
            number -= 1
            roman_number += "I"
        end
    end
    roman_number.reverse
end

puts "Please enter any number and I convert it to"
puts "Old-school Roman numerals."
puts
num = gets.chomp.to_i
puts "Your number #{num} converted to Old-school Roman is:"
puts (old_roman_numeral num)
```

When I run the script, it outputs the correct Roman numerals.

For example 1200 => MCC

But, when I woke up today the first thing I thought was, this can't be right!
The remainder of 1200 % 1000 is 200 and not 0!
But why is the output MCC and not CCCCCCCCCCCC???

Comment: Side note: you may try a more mathematical approach (without `roman_number = ""`, `while`, `-=`, `+=`), it would be a good exercise.

Comment: @tokland yes, I already read Chris Pine's solution at the end of the book. It's more elegant and efficient...

Answer (score 7):

If you trace through the program, it's actually matching the `% 100 == 0` twice first, getting `CC`, and leaving you with 1000. Then it matches `% 1000 == 0`, leaving `CCM`. Finally it reverses the string, leaving you with `MCC`.

---

Side comment: Interesting approach to the problem as I probably would have used a bunch of `>=` comparisons building the string in forward order with special cases for the 'subtraction' parts (`IV` or `IX`). Although on second read, this solution appears to output `IIII` and not `IV`, so the special cases are moot.

Comment: Ahhhh, now I see it! So easy. Thanks a lot for clearing that up!
The first exercise (this one ) is Old Roman style without subtraction. Next one is with subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

the code calculates the digits in reverse order. i.e.

you get a `C` first, then another `C` and in the third iteration of the loop, you get the `M`.

in the end, this line of code:

```
roman_number.reverse
```

reverses `CCM` to `MCC` and thus you get the result you actually get.

to better understand what happens, you can change your code as follows:

```
    if number % 1000 == 0
        number -= 1000
        roman_number += "M"
        next
```

becomes:

```
    if number % 1000 == 0
        number -= 1000
        roman_number += "M"
        puts "number " + number.to_s
        puts "roman_number " + roman_number
        next
```

do this for every if-block. that way you will see what happens in each step.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but just for note, here is a method with similar purpose, taken from my personal library:

```
class Numeric
  RomanNumerals = {
    1000 => "m", 900 => "cm", 500 => "d", 400 => "cd",
    100 => "c", 90 => "xc", 50 => "l", 40 => "xl",
    10 => "x", 9 => "ix", 5 => "v", 4 => "iv", 1 => "i"
  }

  def roman
    return to_s unless 0 < self and self < 4000 # Cannot be romanized
    s, r = "", self
    RomanNumerals.each{|d, c| q, r = r.divmod(d); s.concat(c*q)}
    s
  end
end
```